# Snake active contour algorithm with C++ and OpenCV 3

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, contour

I am trying to implement the snake algorithm for active contour using C++ and OpenCV 3. I am working with the version that uses the gradient descent. As base test I am trying to draw a contour of a lip. This is the base image.

[image: This]

This is the evolution of the contour without external forces (alpha = 0.001, beta = 3, step-size=0.3).

[image: This]

When I add the external force, this is the result.

[image: this]

As external force I have used just the edge detection with Sobel derivative.

[image: Sobel derivative]

This is the code I use for points update.

```
array<Mat, 2> edges = edgeMatrices(croppedImage);
const float ALPHA = 0.001, BETA = 3, GAMMA = 0.3, // Gamma is step size.
    a = GAMMA * ALPHA, b = GAMMA * BETA;
const uint16_t CYCLES = 1000;

const float p = b, q = -a - 4 * b, r = 1 + 2 * a + 6 * b;
Mat pMatrix = pentadiagonalMatrix(POINTS_NUM, p, q, r).inv();

for (uint16_t i = 0; i < CYCLES; ++i) {
    // Extract the x and y derivatives for current points. 
    auto externalForces = external(edges, x, y);

    x = pMatrix * (x + GAMMA * externalForces[0]);
    y = pMatrix * (y + GAMMA * externalForces[1]);

    // Draw the points.
    if (i % 200 == 0 && i > 0)
        drawPoints(croppedImage, x, y, { 0.2f * i, 0.2f * i, 0 });
}
```

This is the code for computing the derivatives.

```
array<Mat, 2> edgeMatrices(Mat &img) {
    // Convert image.
    Mat gray;
    cvtColor(img, gray, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

    // Apply scharr filter.
    Mat grad_x, grad_y, blurred_x, blurred_y;
    int scale = 1;
    int delta = 0;
    int ddepth = CV_16S;
    int kernSize = 3;

    Sobel(gray, grad_x, ddepth, 1, 0, kernSize, scale, delta, BORDER_DEFAULT);
    Sobel(gray, grad_y, ddepth, 0, 1, kernSize, scale, delta, BORDER_DEFAULT);

    GaussianBlur(grad_x, blurred_x, Size(5, 5), 30);
    GaussianBlur(grad_y, blurred_y, Size(5, 5), 30);

    return { blurred_x, blurred_y };
}

array<Mat, 2> external(array<Mat, 2> &edgeMat, Mat &x, Mat &y) {
    array<Mat, 2> ext;
    ext[0] = { Size{ 1, POINTS_NUM }, CV_32FC1 };
    ext[1] = { Size{ 1, POINTS_NUM }, CV_32FC1 };

    for (size_t i = 0; i < POINTS_NUM; ++i) {
        ext[0].at<float>(0, i) = - edgeMat[0].at<short>(y.at<float>(0, i), x.at<float>(0, i));
        ext[1].at<float>(0, i) = - edgeMat[1].at<short>(y.at<float>(0, i), x.at<float>(0, i));
    }

    return ext;
}
```

As you can see, the contour points converge in a very strange way and not towards the edge of the lip (that was the result I would expect).
I am not able to understand if it is an error about implementation or about tuning the parameters or it is just is normal behaviour and I misunderstood something about the algorithm.
I have some doubts on the derivative matrices, I think that they should be regularized in some way, but I am not sure which is the right one. Can someone help me?

The only implementations I have found are of the greedy method.

Comment: You say "error" but forget to describe what did you expect and how it is different from what you achieved?

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was clear.

Comment: Well, hard to say, as you only publish glimbses of your current work... looking at the cyan curve: it looks piecewise in the middle below the lip, so maybe you sample too few points on the curve or your points get unevenly distributed during curve evolution (you typically need to resample the curve at certain intervals). Have you calculated the maximum displacement during the evolution? Maybe your curve is dangling back and forth, which might explain the shape? "Finite-element methods for active contour models and balloons for 2-D and 3-D images" by Cohen&Cohen is worth reading.

Comment: @mainactual I will read the paper and I will update my work. But I have some questions for you: Why I need to resample the curve? What maximum displacement is worth for? My derivative matrix have both negative and positive value since I did no adjustment on Sobel algorithm, do you think I need to shift it on the positive axis (btw, I have added external() code)? And last, since greedy algorithm seems simpler, do you think is worth to go with it?

Comment: Um, brief me what is greedy in this context. You choose the time step s.t. it doesn't jump over features (which consequently causes a backjump and dangling around) and naturally you want to stop evolution at equilibrium (when displacement is small enough) so there's that. Reinitialization is to keep sampling of the curve somewhat even (also to account for growing/shrinking). I think you want the edge potential be minimized at the edges. Gradient magnitude is highest there, but gradient itself, which you put into the for loop is large, so it just pushes your curve away.

Comment: Greedy algorithm is the one described in "Locating Head Boundary by Snakes" by Lam & Yan. For the displacement I got you, I just misunderstood what you had to mean the first time I read the comment, sorry. Reinitialization is something obscure to me, but I read about it in the paper you linked, so I will read it again. 
I didn't get your point about the gradient. Since it is - derivative it should have the minimum at the edges point, isn't it?

Comment: From Cohen&Cohen, `P(v)=-|Grad( I(v) )|^2, F(v)=-Grad( P(v) )` where `P` is the potential map and driving force is `F` while `I` is the input image. What I see, you use `F=-Grad( I(v) )` which is at high value at edges while it should get to zero from both sides. If you correct that + reduce the time step, I guess you can get some convergence.

Comment: @mainactual sorry for late answer, but you spotted the problem, now I have still some difficulties on tuning parameters, but my algorithm definitively works. If you can write an answer I can sign it as correct one. Thank you very much.